# Closing a cmd terminal opened from a powershell terminal?

Tags: powershell, selenium, cmd, codeceptjs

Im currently using the CodeceptJs framework to write automated tests and selenium-standalone server to run them. Basically, I have a folder with a simple test. From a batch file, I run 'selenium-standalone start' to launch selenium and then codeceptjs run to run the test. This passes successfully but the cmd terminal with selenium server running stays open and thus the powershell terminal stays open. I have tried to exit the command using -exit and exit /b, and also tried to kill the cmd but to no avail. Would anyone know how I can close these windows once the script has completed running?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6#outputs

Comment: 'Wait-Process' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Also happens with Stop-Process and Start Process